# Sinhala Unicode Pack re-Installation

Tags: 20.04, unicode

Here are my OS details:

> Ubuntu version - 20.04.2 LTS
>
> Type - 64 bit
>
> GNOME Version - 3.36.8

I'm new to ubuntu. I accidentally deleted the Sinhala language folder while (having fun), changing fonts/ themes, etc. I've tried various solutions given as "Installing Sinhala Unicode Pack" but no success. Now Sinhala letters are showing as this;
[image]

Here are the commands I tried

> sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n language-pack-si
> sudo apt-get install ttf-sinhala-lkmug ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib language-pack-si-base

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select correct package names for your Ubuntu version. Blind googling will not give correct results.

Preliminary package list maybe generated by `check-language-support -l si` and using [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=sinhala&searchon=all) for *sinhala*.

So you can install these packages by

```
sudo apt install --reinstall firefox-locale-si hunspell-si language-pack-gnome-si language-pack-si libreoffice-l10n-si
sudo apt install $(apt-cache search sinhala | awk '{print $1}')
```

and finally to install actual packages for ibus and m17n use command below:

```
sudo apt install ibus-m17n ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db
```

Comment: check-language-support -l si gives 0 results. what should i do

Comment: This means that they are installed. If unsure run `sudo apt install --reinstall firefox-locale-si hunspell-si language-pack-gnome-si language-pack-si libreoffice-l10n-si` .

Comment: with the help of the packages you linked, I tried installing, it made no effect, then I just purged the whole package and reinstalled it. now it is working. thank u

Answer (score 0):

I removed lklug-sinhala. `sudo apt remove fonts-lklug-sinhala`

Now it's working fine.

It seems this package has some issues in Ubuntu 22.04

Please refer this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-lklug-sinhala/+bug/2003843) for more details